# How can I make a message inside a v-for only appear once, if any of the items meets a certain condition?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this v-for, which loops through a set of data.
The data contains some date fields, and I want to run a v-if condition, where a message is shown if any of the dates match the current date.
The problem is that due to the loop, the message will appear 10 times if 10 dates meet the condition, but I only want it to appear once. I have tried various ways to get around this.

This is the original setup:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <div v-if="item.date = currentDate">
       show some message
    </div>
  </div>
<template>

<script>

   import {axiosService} from '@/components/js/axiosService';
   import moment from 'moment/moment';

  data() {
  return {
    currentDate: this.moment(),
    items: null,
  };
},
methods: {
load(){
  getItems() {
    this.items = null;
    axiosService.getItems()
      .then(result => {
        this.items = result.data

      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
   }
  },
watch: {
  $route: 'load'
}
}
</script>
```

Here is what I tried:

Instead of doing a v-for I tried to do a v-if based on a condition triggered by a method. This does not work. messageIsTrue remains false. I have tried both created and mounted

```
<template>
    <div v-if="messageIsTrue">
       show some message
    </div>
<template>

<script>

   import {axiosService} from '@/components/js/axiosService';
   import moment from 'moment/moment';

  data() {
  return {
    messageIsTrue: false
    currentDate: this.moment(),
    items: null,
  };
},
methods: {
load(){
  getItems() {
    this.items = null;
    axiosService.getItems()
      .then(result => {
        this.items = result.data

      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
   }
   checkIfDatesMatch(){
    this.items.forEach(i => {
      if(i.date === this.currentDate){
        this.messageIsTrue = true
      }
    })
  },
  },
created() {
  this.checkIfDatesMatch()
}
watch: {
  $route: 'load'
}
}
</script>
```

I tried putting it in the watcher. This didn't work either. messageIsTrue remains false

```
watch: {
  $route: 'load',
  'items.date'() {
    if(this.items.date === this.currentDate){
      this.messageIsTrue = true
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried making a function in computed:

```
computed: {
  findItemsWithMatchingDates() {
    return this.items.some(item => item.date = this.currentDate)
  },
```

and then run it as an action event:

```
<template>
    <div @action="findItemsWithMatchingDates" v-if="messageIsTrue">
       show some message
    </div>
<template>
```

This will work.... but ONLY if I open up Vue devtools...

I have run out of ideas. What can I do?

Comment: Just use the computed you did in the v-if: `v-if="findItemsWithMatchingDates"`. It will show the message if any date matches and will be updated everytime the items change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need the `v-for`
2. You need a `computed` checking if items' dates include current date, along these lines:

```js
  computed: {
    showMessage() {
      return this.items.map(({ date }) => date).includes(this.currentDate)
    }
  }
```

Note: your computed would have worked too if it evaluated [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (`==`) or [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (`===`), instead of [assigning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) (`=`) <sup>***1***</sup>.

3. Use in template as

```html
<div v-if="showMessage">your message</template>
```

4. Last, but not least, don't reset/init `items` with `null`. Use an empty array (`[]`). This way the array methods (`.some()`, `.includes()`) are still available when data is not present.

---

Working demo <sup>***2***</sup>:

```js
const fromRange = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min
const toDateString = (date = new Date()) => date.toJSON().slice(0, 10)
const getRandomDate = (date = new Date()) => (
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + fromRange(-5, 5)), toDateString(date)
)
const getItems = () =>
  Promise.resolve(
    Array.from({ length: fromRange(3, 12) })
      .map(getRandomDate)
      .map((date) => ({ date }))
  )

new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    items: [],
    currentDate: toDateString()
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.load()
  },
  computed: {
    showMessage() {
      return this.items.map(({ date }) => date).includes(this.currentDate)
      /* or:
      return this.items.some(({ date }) => date === this.currentDate) 
      // */
    },
    isLoading() {
      return !this.items.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    load() {
      this.items = []
      setTimeout(async () => {
        this.items = await getItems()
      }, 1.2e3)
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="isLoading">Loading items...</div>
  <div v-else>
    <div v-if="showMessage">Show the message</div>
    <div v-else>not today. try again tomorrow.</div>
    <button @click="load">Refresh items</button>
  </div>
  <pre
    v-text="JSON.stringify({ dates: items.map(({ date }) => date), currentDate }, null, 2)"
  ></pre>
</div>
```

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - This is quite important. You're also assigning in the `v-if`:

```html
<div v-if="item.date = currentDate">
  show some message
</div>
```

...meaning you assign `currentDate` to each of your items' `date`, in the template, when the item gets rendered. Use `v-if="item.date === currentDate"` instead.
<sup>***2***</sup> - Don't mind the generators, they're only mocking the backend call, and I chose to use dates directly instead of importing `moment`.